# How can I best debug no network connectivity on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to debug a situation that happens when no network connectivity is present for the device.

But how can I simulate this?
As soon as I connect my device using Zune, it get network connectivity automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [preprocessor directive, such as #if DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx), to return false from a custom method.

Or simply, turn off internet on your PC. You can disable the *Local Area Connection* or *Wireless Network Connection* (whatever you use), to disable internet on your PC.

Make sure the phone is in airplane mode at the same time ;-)

Example (works on both phone and emulator):

```
private static bool IsNetworkAvailable()
{
    var available = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();

#if DEBUG
    available = false;
#endif

    return available;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer on that way

```
if (!NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
                MessageBox.Show("You are not connect to the network!");
```

I use it frequently and I make this verification in the App.xaml.cs

Hope it help.

PS: Unfortunately you can not check the network when you are connected to the PC